# IIS 7 on Windows 2008 Server R2 - won't start and can't remove

Tags: iis-7

I stopped IIS7 via the IIS Manager, and now can't restart it! I get the "Cannot start service W3SVC on computer '.'" message. Following that up, I went to try to remove IIS and reinstall.... but when I get to the Windows Features list, IIS is not listed to either Remove OR Add!

Still shows up in IIS manager, but I can't start it.

Anyone got any useful ideas/clues?

Comment: First step for troubleshooting *anything* on Windows Server is to poke around in the Event Log. Something in there will hopefully give you far more information about what's going on when you try to start it.

Comment: yeah - in this case, sadly, it's not really telling me anything beyond that the service couldn't start and that the originator was Microsoft-Windows-WAS. I have found the new location for uninstalling IIS (it's under Roles not Features in Server manager!), so goign to go with that

Answer (score 1):

In the end, reinstalled, repaired .Net framework and created the c:\inetpub\temp\appPools folder (which was missing). [MSDN Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734935%28WS.10%29.aspx)